# Add/Remove dynamic html element on a Django Form

Tags: javascript, django-forms, dom-events

Trying to add logic on a Django form where a text input element should either be appended or removed, based on checkbox's click action. Append of input text works fine, but can't find a way to remove it when the checkbox is unchecked as can't find a right selector for `$(this)` to remove the input.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.tCheck).on('
    click ',function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('div').append('<div id="piiValue"><input text="text" name="+this.value+" required></div>');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('div').remove('#piiValue');
    }
  }
})
```

Forms.py

```
class tOnboardingForm(forms.Form);
      t_choices = (
               ('Name','Name'),
               ('email','email'),
                  )
      tpii = forms.MulitpleChoiceField(required=False,
                                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMulitple(attrs=             {'class':'tCheck'}),
choices=t_choices,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the inserted div can be targeted directly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.tCheck').on('click', function() {
    let $checkbox = $(this);
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      $checkbox.closest('div').append('<div id="piiValue"><input text="text" name="+this.value+" required></div>');
    } else {
      $('#piiValue').remove();   // <-- here
    }
  })
})
```